# Unable to host published asp.net core web application to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, web-applications, hosting

I am trying to host my web application in IIS. It target framework of .NET Core 2.2
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxLsu.jpg)

I published it to publish folder, as Framework-dependent, Runtime to be Portable. then add application from IIS, application pool set to No Managed Code, Pipeline as integrated.
when i click on the Browse *:80 (http) at the right side bar, it prompt me the error in browser of Error 500.19. it just can't run the web application.

But then when i navigate to this folder running it using cmd. dotnet WebApplication.dll then this application is running, listening on localhost:5001.
[run using cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MToh4.jpg)

Anyone know how can i configure it properly in IIS?

My default binding
[binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf9WE.jpg)

SSL settings error [SSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Lwd.jpg)

Comment: Have you checked your site's bindings to see the port it's listening to?

Comment: @MartinFerrari May i know how to check it??

Comment: @XylanDaniel You can refer to this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-build-simple-asp-net-core-website/

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as answer so I can attach an image.
1 - Open IIS
2 - Expand "Sites"
3 - Right click on the desired site
4 - Select Edit Bindings
You should see the host name and port your site is binded to.

Right click on your site, then choose "Edit Bindings". It will tell you the port your site is listening to.

[image]

Comment: Martin, my site binding is default as when i turn on the IIS. I had attached my screenshot in the question there

Comment: Ok. Have you checked that both the site and the app pool are running? For the site, right click the site name, select "Manage WebSite". For the Application Pool, right click the Application Pool name. For both of cases, you have a "Start" menu option in the contextual menus.

Comment: The application pool is started, i checked. 
but then i found out something is that when i double click on my site SSL Settings, it prompt me some error but no tell me what is the error in web.config file. i had attached the screenshot in the question.

Comment: You should access your site just with "localhost" I think, or do you have a "publish" endpoint? But there's another configuration error, have you checked the Event Viewer to see if you find more details?